# what to do about 'aw snap, something went wrong while displaying this page, Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT' error in js

Tags: javascript, debugging

my javascript game was working this morning, and then I added some code and got this:['aw snap, something went wrong while displaying this page, Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy3pC.png). I deleted the code that i added but the error still came up.

after i changed my code back and it still didn't work, i did some internet research and here is what i tried (to no avail):

restarting my computer,

clearing my cache and cookies,

trying on a different web browser,

opening Devtools (it said that devtools was disconnected).

getting off school wifi in case they blocked it

i am using an online code editor and i tried running some of my other programs on it and they still worked. i also tried downloading the project and trying without my code editor. that didn't work either.
any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was calling a for loop with a float range instead of an int. I don't know why this crashed the website instead of coming up on the dev tools console, but the problem is solved now.